# Kotlin: initialize 2D array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I am in a loop, reading 2 columns from a file. I read R, T combinations, 50 times. I want R and T to be in an array so I can look up the Nth pair of R, T later in a function. How do I put the R, T pairs in an array and look up the, say, 25th entry later in a function?

For example:

```
for (nsection in 1 until NS+1) {
  val list: List<String> = lines[nsection + 1].trim().split("\\s+".toRegex())
  val radius = list[0].toFloat()
  println("Radius = $radius")
  val twist = list[8].toFloat()
  println("twist = $twist")
  }
```

Would like to pull radius and twist pairs from a table in a function later. NS goes up to 50 so far.

Comment: It's probably clearer if you share the existing code you have

Comment: I added a block of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` on your range iterator to produce a List of what you want.

```
val radiusTwistPairs: List<Pair<Float, Float>> = (1..NS).map { nsection ->
    val list = lines[nsection + 1].trim().split("\\s+".toRegex())
    val radius = list[0].toFloat()
    println("Radius = $radius")
    val twist = list[8].toFloat()
    println("twist = $twist")
    radius to twist
}
```

Or use an Array constructor:

```
val radiusTwistPairs: Array<Pair<Float, Float>> = Array(NS) { i ->
    val list = lines[i + 2].trim().split("\\s+".toRegex())
    val radius = list[0].toFloat()
    println("Radius = $radius")
    val twist = list[8].toFloat()
    println("twist = $twist")
    radius to twist
}
```

Comment: How do I pull back out the 25th twist values?

Comment: `radiusTwistPairs[24]`

Comment: does that pull a pair, or just twist?

Comment: That's a pair. If you want the second part of the pair (the twist) use `.second` on it.

Comment: Ok... I'll try to put the whole thing in an i-loop to try and load up a radiusTwistPairs array...  do I put a loop around it, or inside?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A loop for what? This already internally loops and outputs the full list or array.

Comment: Yep. I am not familiar with implicit Kotlin loops, but all works perfectly. Thank!

Comment: There are a bunch of functions for Iterators (Lists are Iterators) where you pass a lambda that is used to iterate on their contents and output a List. `map` is a common one.

Comment: I have your code inside a Try. I am able to access radiusTwistPairs as long as I am inside the Try, but compile gives me an Unresolved Reference if I try to access radiusTwistPairs outside the Try-Catch. I am surprised. Do you have an idea? val twist1 = radiusTwistPairs[24].second

Comment: Any variable declared inside brackets cannot be accessed outside those brackets. You will have to declare `radiusTwistPairs` before the `try/catch`. If this is something you need to access completely outside this function, you should declare it as a class property. But if you just need to access it after try/catch, then declare it right before the try block. So `val radiusTwistPairs: Array<Pair<Float, Float>>? = null` before `try`.

Comment: I placed that declaration before the try, and now the compiler is complaining where I first try to use the array:  Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Array<Pair<Float, Float>>?

Comment: I tried accessing like this, with same error:   val twist = radiusTwistPairs?.get(section-1).second

Comment: If you use `?.`, you get the result or null if the first thing was null, so now you have a `Pair?` and once again would need either `!!` or `?.` to call something on it. I don't know what's going on in your `try/catch`, but your function cannot complete without a successful `try` block, you could return from the `catch` block and then you wouldn't need to make the `radiusTwistPairs` nullable. You would just declare it without assigning it.

Comment: But if it is possible to finish what you're doing even if `radiusTwistPairs` is null, then you can surround the code that relies on it in an `if (radiusTwistPairs != null) {}` check and it will be smart-casted to non-nullable inside the `if` block.